# Azure AD B2C user info Xamarin

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-ad-b2c

Hello I am trying to get user info like name and address in an Xamarin app using Azure AD B2C for authentication.

So far I've gotten the authentication working fine

```cs
public async Task<MobileServiceUser> LoginAsync(MobileServiceClient client, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider)
{
  try
  {
    //login and save user status
    var user = await client.LoginAsync(Forms.Context, provider);

    Settings.AuthToken = user?.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken ?? string.Empty;
    Settings.UserId = user?.UserId ?? string.Empty;
    return user;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
  }

  return null;
}
```

However I would like to know how to get the user's name and birthday. I haven't been able to find a clear course of action for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not explicitly get this information using the MobileService SDK. Check out the complete documentation about App Service Authentication/Authorization [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview).

You will reach the point where it mentions:

> Your application can also obtain additional user details through an
>   HTTP GET on the `/.auth/me` endpoint of your application. A valid token
>   that's included with the request will return a JSON payload with
>   details about the provider that's being used, the underlying provider
>   token, and some other user information. The Mobile Apps server SDKs
>   provide helper methods to work with this data.

So, in your Xamarin, after the user is successfully authentication, you have to explicitly make a HTTP GET request to `/.auth/me` and parse the result to get all information about the logged-in user.

Not sure how to do this in Xamarin, but here is how to do it in C# UWP (Universal Windows Platform):

```
                var url = App.MobileService.MobileAppUri + "/.auth/me";
                var clent = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
                clent.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ZUMO-AUTH", this.user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
                var userData = await clent.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
```

at the of this code execution, the userData varibale will be a JSON srting with all user's claims.

Comment: This works. Thanks you. I've been busting my brain over the last few days. There is a ton of conflicting info currently. It doesn't help that Mobile Service became mobile apps and they seems to have a lot in common.  Thanks a million!

Comment: Do you know if there is an object I can cast the response to in order to be able to use the data?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure whether there is already an object you could use for deserialization. Just a hint - what you get is a pure JSON STRING, you cannot `cast` a JSON string, you can `deserialise` it. But still, I don't know what object you should use. Check the structure and dynamic, or design your object. It should be close to the [ClaimsPrincipal Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'd kiss you if I could!  Why is it necessary to jump through all these hoops for some very basic info?  The documentation is poor for "AAD" but so is the implementation.  This and having to jump back and forth between the new and old portal...what a joke.  Dear MSFT -> Get AAD right!